# Retrieving response string from Async. web request

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, compact-framework

I have been working on this a couple of days looking for an answer on the internet and there doesn't seem to be a good one for compact framework.

What I need to do is get the response string from GetResponseCallBack and pass it back to the main thread to update the GUI.

Has anyone done this in compact framework? I am using .NET 3.5

Here are my two callbacks

```
private static void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

    // End the operation
    Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);


    string postData = "&location=funville";

    // Convert the string into a byte array. 
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    // Write to the request stream.
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length);
    postStream.Close();

    // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
}

private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

    // End the operation
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
    Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
    string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
    // Close the stream object
    streamResponse.Close();
    streamRead.Close();

    // Release the HttpWebResponse
    response.Close();
    allDone.Set();
}
```

Here is the code I use to create the request

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.SendChunked = true;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// Set the Method property to 'POST' to post data to the URI.
request.Method = "POST";

// start the asynchronous operation
request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);

// Keep the main thread from continuing while the asynchronous 
// operation completes. A real world application 
// could do something useful such as updating its user interface. 
allDone.WaitOne();
```

It is mainly just the default code from MSDN, and I am getting the correct response data because I had a MessageBox pop the response string in the call back I just need some direction on passing it to the main thread.

Comment: I've never understood this, maybe you can help me since your asking this question. Why are you making it Async, just to put a WaitOne right after the call? Doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of Async calls? Plus your asking a web page, not sure who wrote that web page, to call you back, over the web? I've never done Async calls over the web, so sorry if I'm asking a stupid question.

Comment: I was using sync calls and it was locking the main thread while the call was being made, which was fine when I was setting it to make a call every 50 seconds but I need it to make a call every 5 seconds without freezing the rest of the application.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Awesome, thanks John. I guess I got in the habit of typing it into google so I just forgot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have code that will notify the main thread using the `allDone` event. You can put the result in a variable that's visible to the main thread and then call `allDone.Set`. When the main thread sees that the event is set, it can then get the result from that variable.

Your primary problem appears to be how to determine if the result is ready. That's a bit of a harder problem and depends on what the main thread is doing. If the main thread is waiting for user input, then you could replace the event and global variable with an [event-based asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The key would be to marshal the event to the UI thread using something like [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If your main thread is doing something else, then it will have to poll the `allDone` event from time to time. Something like:

```
while (!allDone.WaitOne(0))
{
    // do stuff
}
// get and process result
```

Or:

```
while (true)
{
    if (allDone.WaitOne(0))
    {
        // get and process result
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah the main thread has no problem doing things in the background, my issue is that I need to get the variable from the static callback GetResponseCallBack. When I put a global variable in that section it gives an object reference is required for the non-static field

Comment: @Chitowns24: Then either make the global a static, make the callback an instance method, or pass a reference to the result in the `state` parameter to `BeginGetResponse`. (You'll have to wrap that and the request in a class or a `Tuple`.)

Comment: Wow. changing the variable from global to static did the trick. I wish I would have posted this 4 days ago when I started working on it! Thank you Jim!

Comment: Glad you got your answer, but I would suggest creating a thread to handle your web communications vs a callback.   What if there is a network blip and you never get the callback?  How would you know?  Good luck.